# Dynamically construct JSON payload from string in specific format in C#

Tags: c#, json, excel

Can you please help me in fixing this issue.

I am trying to construct JSON payload dynamically by reading the string in specific format from excel sheet.

```
Example :
String in excel columns - 
 "books[].Categories[].Name"
 "books[].Categories[].Type"
```

```
JSON - 
{
  "books":[
    {
      "Categories":[
                {
                  "Name":"Solo",
                  "Type":"Drama"
                }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Logic - Split the string using '.' and each string should be a property and any string containing "[]" should be a List.
In this way we can read the path from excel sheet and construct request and response JSON payloads for posting and validating an API.
I know how to read the batches from Excel sheet. I want to know how to dynamically make string as property name so that code should convert the values in excel columns as JSON payload with provided strings as properties name.

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, where do you get "Solo" and "Drama" from?

Comment: What happens if you have `"books[].Categories[].Name"` then another `"books[].Categories[].Name"`?

Comment: As a help, I can think about using *Composite* design pattern for gathering string inputs to some composite-objects(root/branch/leaf), after that using those objects to create your json, but please ask about your specific problem here -HTH ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
var input = new List<(string path, string value)>
{
    ("books[].Categories[].Name", "Solo"),
    ("books[].Categories[].Type", "Drama"),
    ("books[].Categories[].Name", "Dougal and the blue cat"),
    ("books[].Categories[].Type", "Trippy"),
};

var result = new JObject();

foreach (var (path, value) in input)
{
    var pathParts = path.Split('.');
    JContainer parentNode = result;
    foreach (var unsanitisedPathPart in pathParts)
    {
        bool isArray = unsanitisedPathPart.EndsWith("[]");
        string pathPart = isArray
                    ? unsanitisedPathPart.Substring(0, unsanitisedPathPart.Length - "[]".Length)
                    : unsanitisedPathPart;
        JContainer currentNode = null;

        if (parentNode is JArray parentArray)
        {
            // Does the last element of the parent contain an object/value with this path?
            // If so, we need to add a new element
            var lastElementProperty = parentArray.Last?.Value<JToken>(pathPart);
            if (lastElementProperty != null && (lastElementProperty is JArray) != isArray)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Path part '{unsanitisedPathPart}' in '{path}' changed whether it was an array");
            }

            if (parentArray.Last == null || lastElementProperty is JObject || lastElementProperty is JValue)
            {
                currentNode = isArray ? (JContainer)new JArray() : new JObject();
                var newChild = new JObject()
                {
                    { pathPart, currentNode }
                };
                parentArray.Add(newChild);
            }
            else
            {
                parentNode = (JObject)parentArray.Last;
                // Fall through into the 'parentNode is JObject' case below
            }
        }
        if (parentNode is JObject parentObject)
        {
            // Does this element exist yet? If not, add it
            currentNode = parentObject.Value<JContainer>(pathPart);
            if (currentNode == null)
            {
                currentNode = isArray ? (JContainer)new JArray() : new JObject();
                parentObject.Add(pathPart, currentNode);
            }
        }
        Trace.Assert(currentNode != null);

        parentNode = currentNode;
    }

    if (parentNode is JObject finalObject)
    {
        ((JProperty)finalObject.Parent).Value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Final element must not be an array in '{path}'");
    }
}

string resultJson = result.ToString();
```

We keep the result as a `JObject`. For each path, we split it on `.` to get each of its parts, then walk through them, and at the same time walk down the object hierarchy from the outermost `JObject`, adding new elements to the object hierarchy as we go.

The tricky bit is determining when to add new elements to arrays. The logic is "if the array is empty, or the last element in the array already has the specified key". Note that it's not allowed to have arrays which directly contain arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the code. This is what I was looking for. I will have to handle the scenario having multiple "books[].Categories[].Name" like ("books[].Categories[].Name", "Solo, Dougal and the blue cat"). I will work on that.